# typo3 includes files from wrong path

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

#### Setup

- Typo3 10.4.16  (classic installation: NO composer!)

Structure:

```
/html/typo3
|
+--- typo3_src
+--- typo3
+--- typo3conf
+--- typo3temp
+--- index.php
```

Configuration works fine on localhost

#### Issue

I copied everything onto the remote machine, adjusted database, domain config, sites, ...

Now, if I open the domain in my browser i get the following error:

```
Warning: require(/.../html/typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/DefaultConfiguration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /html/typo3/typo3_src-10.4.16/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.php on line 92
```

Of couse, the file cannot be found, because the include path should be `/.../html/typo3/typo3/sysext/...` (see file structure above).

- I can reach the backend and the install tool. Both works fine. No issues there as far as I know.

Why is typo3 including the wrong path here?
What did I miss?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The [TYPO3 Installation and Upgrade Guide](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/10.4/en-us/QuickInstall/GetAndUnpack/Index.html) provides details about how the directory structure should look like.

If you don't use a [Composer-based installation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/10.4/en-us/QuickInstall/Composer/Index.html) (Composer is by the way the recommended installation method today), make sure that you create [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to specific target directories. These are the three entries with the `->` sign in the following example:

```
www
├── public
│   ├── fileadmin
│   ├── index.php -> typo3_src/index.php
│   ├── typo3 -> typo3_src/typo3
│   ├── typo3conf
│   ├── typo3_src -> ../typo3_src-10.4.16
│   └── typo3temp
└── typo3_src-10.4.16
    ...
```

The `public/` directory is typically the *document root* (e.g. `DocumentRoot` in an Apache web server configuration). Inside `public/` you create the following symbolic links:

- `typo3_src` points to the directory `typo3_src-10.4.x` in the **parent** level.
- `index.php` points to the same file name inside `typo3_src`.
- `typo3` points to the same file/folder name inside `typo3_src`.

This officially recommended structure lets you organize all files of the TYPO3 source package separated from other files of your installation. One benefit of this approach is that you can use the **Core Update** function in TYPO3's Admin Tools to easily update your TYPO3 installation.

Comment: Note to my future self:
Double and *tiple* check the targets of the symlinks!

Thank you and best regards, mt